# ListView takes up all space in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I have this `LinearLayout` containing a `ListView` and a `LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="Hej"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The `ListView` takes up the entire layout and the `LinearLayout` with `EditText` gets added below the bottom edge of the screen and isn't visible. How can I fix this? I tried with `layout_weight` but didn't work.

Comment: By the way, `match_parent` and `fill_parent` do the exact same thing. No need to use them both. And in fact, you should only be using `match_parent` because `fill_parent` was deprecated in API 8.

Comment: @NoChinDeluxe Thanks for the clarification, I thought they were different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because you are using `fill_parent`, and it will do exactly that.

You could try something along the lines of this... It will cause the ListView to expand to fill the space.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="Hej"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Another alternative is to use a RelativeLayout. So long as the height of the ListView is not [wrap_content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4270471/503508), it should be OK.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="Hej"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would fill as much as it could and not do exactly like match_parent. I can accept in 10 min

Comment: `fill_parent` is deprecated, and equivalent to `match_parent`, use the later instead.

Comment: Perhaps thats why fill_parent is deprecated because its misleading :)

Comment: Never gave much thought about that. Makes sense!